# JSXGraph: Applying a line transformation with applyOnce()

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I'm trying to apply a one-time transformation to a Line in JSXGraph.

Based on the [documentation](https://jsxgraph.org/wiki/index.php/Transformations#3.29_One-time_application_of_a_transformation_to_a_point.), I'm trying to transform a Line like this:

```
var f = function(x) {
    return x;
};

var l1 = board.create('functiongraph', [f], {
    name: 'line 1',
    withLabel: true,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeColor: 'orange',
    fixed: false
});

// Rotate about an intersection point with another line
var i = board.create('intersection', [l1, l2, 0], {
    name: 'intersection',
    fixed: true,
    showInfobox: false
});

var rot = board.create(
    'transform', [
        function() {
            // This gets the value from a slider
            return s.Value();
        }, i
    ], {
        type:'rotate'
    });

rot.applyOnce(l1);
board.update();
```

The full source is here: http://maldive.ccnmtl.columbia.edu/js/ncustom.js and you can see the error I'm describing here: http://maldive.ccnmtl.columbia.edu/js/functiongraph-rotation.html

I get the error: `t[n].coords is undefined`. In the full application that I'm trying this in, I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'usrCoords' of undefined`

So, anyways, has anyone else tried to transform a line like this?

---

**Update:** After looking at the [source](https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph/blob/master/src/base/transformation.js#L353), it's obvious this method only works with points. So, I don't know if this will be possible with my functiongraph. I am just using a straight line here though, so it's possible I can do something with points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `applyOnce` is implemented only for points, texts and images, yet. The alternative is to bind the transformation to the curve. Here is the full example (relevant is only the very last line):

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
  boundingbox: [-10, 10, 10, -10],
  axis:true
});

var f = function(x) {
    return x;
};

var l1 = board.create('functiongraph', [f], {
    name: 'line 1', withLabel: true, fixed: false
});

var f2 = function(x) {
    var alpha = 0.3;
    return (1 - alpha) *
        (1.4 *
         1.6 ** alpha) *
        (x ** -alpha);
};

var l2 = board.create('functiongraph', [f2], {
    name: 'line 2', withLabel: true, fixed: false
});


// Rotate about an intersection point with another line
var intrsct = board.create('intersection', [l1, l2, 0], {
    name: 'intersection', fixed: true,
});

var s = board.create(
    'slider', [
        [-1, -1],
        [2, -1],
        [0, 0, 2]
    ], { name:'angle'});

var rot = board.create(
    'transform', [
        function() {
            // This gets the value from a slider
            return s.Value();
        }, intrsct
    ], { type:'rotate' });

rot.bindTo(l1);
```

Alternatively, in the upcoming version 0.99.7 (already available in the nightly builds), you can create a new curve which is the transformed curve of an original curve:

```
var l1a = board.create('curve', [l1, rot], {
    name: 'line 1a',
    withLabel: true,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeColor: 'orange',
    fixed: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Binding the transformation to the curve works great. I'm having an issue embedding this in a react application though: If I have a curve with a "generic" transformation applied just to set its x/y positioning, then add a "rotation" transform, because of how i have set things up, the rotation transform is applied to the curve each time it's dragged, rotating it over and over again. I realize this is outside the scope of JSXGraph, though - I just need to re-think how I'm doing this.